# jni library not getting included in debug build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android debug build is missing the .so files in the jniLibs folder.

Project level build.gradle given below

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app level build.gradle given below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.mobiocean"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs 'src/main/jniLibs'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

[image: Project file structure]

however if I do a Build -> Rebuild Project, the generated apk has the required .so files. But when I am connected to the device and running the application the apk is not including the required .so files.

I have checked the build/intermediates/merged_jni_libs folder, it contains the required files in all cases.

I am using Android Studio 3.5 and using Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.0 and Gradle version 5.4.1

Comment: What `make` are you using ? `externalNativeBuild`,`ndkBuild`, `Cmake`.... I think you just need to copy the *.so files into the lib/jniLibs directory. What does your file system structure look like ? More gradle please.

Comment: I am using prebuilt native libraries, hence not using make. The *.so files are copied into the jniLibs. [Following this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#jniLibs)

Comment: What is the point of following that link ?, I already know how it works and it builds correctly ;O)

Comment: That's the point, its not building correctly for me. But I am really starting to suspect that is Gradle Plugin Issue, it works fine in Gradle 3.1.4, but not in 3.5.0

Comment: That's why I asked you **What does your file system structure look like ? More gradle please** then I can compare it with mine, and advise you. Root and app level `build.gradle`. I have built **VERY** complex `JNI` `systems. Share and enjoy` - **Sirius Cybernetics Corporation** Well, you answered your own question.

Comment: Added gradle and file structure

Comment: If *"it works fine in `Gradle 3.1.4`, but not in `3.5.0`"* then we are close to a solution either a *bug* in  `3.5.0` **OR** your not following a *new rule* convention for `3.5.0`. At least you have a workaround. More to follow. No warnings/errors on build ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200315/discussion-between-saha-k-p-ghoshal-and-jon-goodwin).

Comment: Build succeeds all the time, also no warnings. It even works when I do a rebuild project (in 3.5.0). just not when I am trying to run directly on a device.

Comment: UNIX or Windows build machine ?I think your *`.so files` may feel more comfortable in:`~AndroidStudioProjectsMobiOcean/app/libs` (worth copying them there). Your only providing libraries for armeabi ? Not allowed for Play store any more! You need 64-bit *.so. **Wow** so many thigs wrong! Do you intend to publish in play store ? Or just for yourself ?

Comment: This is not intended for Play store, for a specific device, running a custom android build. I had tried putting things in libs folder, but it made no change. Build machine is Fedora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitlty adding the architecure variants to the app grade file also helps:

```
  buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi"
            }
        }
        debug {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround:

1. run "Build" in AS
2. install the apk on your device and run it
3. attach debugger to the process

I think it's a bug of AS. I met the same problem: "Build" or run "gradlew :app:assembleDebug" worked, while run debug not. If there is a bug in Gradle of Gradle plugin, then "Build" or "gradlew :app:assembleDebug" should also fail.